# Can I use Google AdSense within a banner rotator?

Tags: google-adsense

I have 3 rotating banners on one 728x90 position on my website, so every time a page is loaded another banner is shown. One of these is AdSense.

Is it legal, I mean is this strictly prohibited or not?

Because, the code is basically stored in db table in my CMS module in Wordpress, so I guess it is OK.

But I am asking to be sure.

What is your personal experience?

Does Google penalize sites with banner rotators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't use more than 3 AdSense units per page, it is OK.

In fact, in their DFP platform, they also use AdSense in "ad rotators" (ad units.)